# Matlab PSNR for audio

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I tried to find PSNR between 2 WAV file. I have copied the code but still wrong

```
[y1,fs1]=audioread('phon.wav');
[y2,fs2]=audioread('dekrip_phon.wav');
[c1x,c1y]=size(y1);
[c2x,c2y]=size(y2);
%Signal1 = audioread('phon.wav');
%Signal2 = audioread('dekrip_phon.wav');
%RMS1 = rms(Signal1)
%RMS2 = rms(Signal2)
 R=c1x;
 C=c1y;

 err = sum((y1-y2)/(R*C));
 MSE=sqrt(err);
 MAXVAL=65535;
  PSNR = 20*log10(MAXVAL/MSE);

  disp(['mse=' num2str(MSE) ' PSNR=' num2str(PSNR)]);
```

And I just getting this error message

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in PSNRtest (line 12)
 err = sum((y1-y2)/(R*C));
```

I tried call using whos and this the result

```
>> whos y1
  Name            Size               Bytes  Class     Attributes

  y1        1636992x2             26191872  double              

>> whos y2
  Name            Size               Bytes  Class     Attributes

  y2        1432391x2             22918256  double
```

I read other articlle its must same size. Can I resize the y2 or y1 and make it same ? If cannot, what method I must use to compare 2 signal audio for the noise ? Thanks

Comment: The arrays need to be the same size. If the two audio files are recorded independently, you won’t be able to compare them directly, as they likely will not start at the exact same moment. Even a 1 sample shift between the two signals makes this method useless. This method is really intended to compare a signal with a filtered version of itself.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have revise the audio and did it. But when I use another audio and the size is same I got this error

Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in PSNRtest (line 15)
  PSNR = 20*log10(MAXVAL/MSE);

Comment: Make sure `MSE` there is a single value. Not sure why it wouldn’t be, maybe a stereo signal? Add `err=sum(err)` before computing `MSE`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Its work !!! But if make both audio in same size, It means the PSNR score unlimited ? Because I get the score 143.9646-13.64376i and 151.3849-13.64376i

Comment: @CrisLuengo for value of MAXVAL is it standard or must be another value ?

Comment: I don’t expect complex values from this computation. `MAXVAL` should be the largest value in the signal. Something like `max(y1(:))`.

Comment: @AhmadRoyhan please update your post with the actual question.